# Get several Uninstall Strings from Registry with Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry, uninstallstring

I want to uninstall a program. There can be several versions of this program installed at the same time. I want to uninstall them with the uninstall string from the registry.

I need to get the subkeys of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
which contain the words "jump client" and "cloud". If the name of the subkey contains these words, then I need to get the Display Name and the Uninstall String. The Display Name also contains these two words.

For example:
I need the Uninstall String and Display Name of "123-Jump Client – 189.38-cloud" and the Uninstall String and Display Name of "245-Jump Client – 184-cloud".
[image]

I tried

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"|Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -contains "jump client" -and $_.DisplayName -contains "cloud"}
```

That does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementing [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74182015/7571258), you may already filter by using wildcards for the `-Path` argument of the `Get-ItemProperty` command:

```sh
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*Jump Client*cloud" | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, UninstallString
```

In case the software is 32-bit, then on a 64-bit Windows, you'd have to search in the 32-bit view of the registry:

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*Jump Client*cloud" | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, UninstallString
```

See [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry)

Answer (score 3):

The `-contains` operator searches for an item in an **array** of items (exact, though case-insensitive match).

In your case you would use

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | 
Where-Object {$_.PSChildName -like '*jump client*cloud'} | 
Select-Object DisplayName, UninstallString
```

<sup>The [-contains operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#comparison-operators) is often confused with the string objects [.Contains() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) which searches for a substring within a string.</sup>

Comment: Does not work. No key found